# "Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation" for a very simple C program

Tags: c, valgrind

I have been following Learn C The Hard Way till exercise 6 and I frequently encounter this error without any idea on how to solve it.

I'm pretty new to C and am not sure what this means, most questions with this valgrind error is due to referencing uninitialised values, but in this case isn't distance already explicitly initialised right before it is called?

I am on a Mac, OS X 10.10.2 (14C109).

Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN installed via brew, brew install --HEAD valgrind.

Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int distance = 100;
    printf("You are %d miles away.\n", distance);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the relevant part of my valgrind log:

```
==14578== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14578==    at 0x1003FBC3F: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Haswell (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==14578==    by 0x1001EFB96: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==14578==    by 0x1001F9FE5: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==14578==    by 0x10021F9AE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==14578==    by 0x10021FC80: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==14578==    by 0x1001F5B71: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==14578==    by 0x1001F39D7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==14578==    by 0x100000F46: main (ex6.c:6)
==14578==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14578==    at 0x1001F5BF8: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==14578== 
You are 100 miles away.
```

Comment: Does the message persist if you declare main not like a function taking an unknown but fixed number of arguments, but like a function taking no arguments: `int main(void)`?

Comment: This looks like a false alarm, you need to be sure that the `valgrind` version you are running was compiled with support for your current c library, i have seen this kind of problems when valgrind was compiled in a different linux distro than the one running it.

Comment: This program does not produce the valgrind output you produced on my setup (stock Ubuntu 14.04). Please post the gcc settings you used, and the valgrind command line, and version numbers of both.

Comment: @remyabel `libsystem_platform.dylib` so yes it is Mac, do you know something about this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64; valgrind is happy with your code. (using GCC 4.9.2)

Comment: I am on a Mac, OS X 10.10.2 (14C109).
Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN installed via brew, brew install --HEAD valgrind.

Comment: @stupid If you can download the source code and compile it, I promise the error will go away...